# Separating logic and UI in my React component/API request

Tags: reactjs, components, separation-of-concerns

I'm relative new to React and I am attempting to take a sloppily written component and make it more semantic by separating logic from the UI i.e. a dumb component and a smart component rather than both jumbled together.

Here is the sloppy component I'm working with:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from "axios";

class CoinList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      coinList: []
    };
  }



  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist`)
    .then(res => {
      const coins = res.data;
      this.setState({ coinList: coins});
    });
  }



// Object.keys is used to map through the data. Can't map through the data without this because the data is not an array. Map can only be used on arrays.
render() {
  const data = this.state.coinList.Data;
  if (data == null) return null;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
        <div className="container">
          <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th className="col-md-2">Coin</th>
              <th className="col-md-2">Symbol</th>
              <th className="col-md-2">Algorithm</th>
              <th className="col-md-2">#</th>
            </tr>
           </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td className="col-md-2">{data[key].CoinName}</td>
                <td className="col-md-2">{key}</td>
                <td className="col-md-2">{data[key].Algorithm}</td>
                <td className="col-md-2">{data[key].SortOrder}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
 }
}


export default CoinList;
```

I have attempted to separate concerns by taking this code and breaking it up into two separate components. Here is what I have thus far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CoinListItem from './coinListItem.js';


export default class NewCoinList extends Component {

  renderList() {
    const data = this.state.coinList.Data;
    if (data == null) return null;

      return Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
          <CoinListItem
            key={key}
          />

    ))
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <table className='table table-striped'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="col-md-2">Coin</th>
            <th className="col-md-2">Symbol</th>
            <th className="col-md-2">Algorithm</th>
            <th className="col-md-2">#</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.renderList()}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }


}
```

And this:

```
import React from 'react';


const CoinListItem = (props) => {
  const data = this.state.coinList.Data;
  if (data == null) return null;

  return (
    <tr>
      <td className="col-md-2">{props.data[key].CoinName}</td>
      <td className="col-md-2">{props.key}</td>
      <td className="col-md-2">{props.data[key].Algorithm}</td>
      <td className="col-md-2">{props.data[key].SortOrder}</td>
    </tr>

  );

};


export default CoinListItem;
```

I am getting an error in CoinListItem that says "Key is not defined". Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to properly separate this component into two components that are more semantic?

Answer (score 1):

Well on your coinlistitem you used:

```
              const data = this.state.coinList.Data;
```

infact you passed the data as a prop , and not a state. You might aswell do this :

```
    renderList() {
           const data = this.state.coinList.Data;
           if (data == null) return null;

  return data.map((singleData,key) => (
      <CoinListItem
        key={key}
        singleData= { singleData }
      />

))
}
```

then use it on your coinlistitem like this :

```
         const { singleData } = this.props;


       return (
            <tr>
              <td className="col-md-2">{singleData.CoinName}</td>
              <td className="col-md-2">{singleData.key}</td>
               <td className="col-md-2">{singleData.Algorithm}</td>
              <td className="col-md-2">{singleData.SortOrder}</td>
              </tr>

  );

};
```

Comment: Would I be better off passing it as state?

Comment: Well a State from your parent component passed in to its children is already considered as a prop.